# Inserir meses não existentes no array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Estou colocando em um `array` o valor total de vendas por mês. O código está funcionando perfeitamente, mas preciso que o `javascript` verifique quais meses não está nesse array e preencha ele na ordem 1 ao 12. Por exemplo:

O código gerou um array assim:

> [{4:3094}, {6:9873}, {7:6531}, {12:10937}]

Então tem os meses `4, 6, 7 e 12`.

Preciso que o código insira os outros meses `(1,2,3,5,8,9,10,11)` nesse array com o valor de **0** e deixe na ordem de meses que são `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`

Tenho o código:

```
var resultadosOne = {};
var highchartsOne = [];

for (ano in resultadosOne) {

            var mesVendaArray = [];

            for(mes in resultadosOne[ano]){

                var vendaMes = 0;

                resultadosOne[ano][mes].forEach((venda) => {

                    VendaFormatada = venda.replace(",", ".");

                    if(VendaFormatada <= 0){
                        VendaFormatada = 0;
                    }

                    vendaMes += parseFloat(VendaFormatada);
                });

                mesVendaArray.push({mes:mes, venda: vendaMes});
            };

            if(ano != ""){
                highchartsOne.push({name:ano, data:mesVendaArray, color:'#6AB241'});
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Método 1**: Para fazer funcionar

```js
var mesVendaArray = [{4:3094}, {6:9873}, {7:6531}, {12:10937}];

for (m = 1; m < 12; m++) {            // Para todos os meses possíveis,

  var found = false;

  mesVendaArray.forEach(function(v) { // para todos os itens de mesVendaArray,

    if (!!v[m]){                      // O mês está presente:
      found = true;                   // marque como achado.
    }

  });            

  if (!found) {                       // O mês não foi achado: Crie a entrada.
    var o = {};
    o[m] = 0;
    mesVendaArray.push(o);
  }

}

console.log(mesVendaArray);
```

Entretanto eu não diria que esta é a melhor maneira.

**Método 2**: Crie um objeto com várias propriedades

Ao invés de

```
mesVendaArray.push({mes:mes, venda: vendaMes});
```

Utilize

```
mesVendaObj[mes] = vendaMes;
```

Benefício: Um único objeto contendo todo o resultado do mês:

```
mesVendaObj // {4:3094, 6:9873, 7:6531, 12:10937}
```

Você pode então incializá-lo com

```
for (m = 1; m < 12; m++) { mesVendaObj[m] = 0 ; }
```

Antes de iniciar a sumarização.

Comment: Estou tentando utilizar seu método 1 e ele duplica os meses que tem. Por exemplo, se tem 5 meses com os valores de venda ele pega e completa do 1 ao 12 mais joga +5 totalizando 17.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Obrigado por apontar, fiz uma pequena correção - teste o novo código.

Comment: não testei se esse último seu funciona, mas fiz uma alteração na linha e deixei assim: **if (v.mes == m){ found = true; }** e funcionou parcialmente, depois só tive que ordenar com sort() e fazer uma função dentro do sort para ordenar o campo **mes** ai deu certinho. Obrigado

Comment: Estava a dois dias batendo cabeça e tua função me ajudou a achar a resposta correta para o problema. Obrigado @OnoSendai

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um for executando de 1 a 12, e verificar se o número da iteração já existe no seu mesVendaArray, senão existir você popula com {i: 0}.

Ou

Pode usar um utilitario como o lodash e fazer um merge com um array já pré-populado com 0:

```
var defaultArrayData = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0,10:0,11:0,12:0};
var mesVendaData = _.merge(defaultArrayData, mesVendaArray);
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#merge

Comment: **arrumei uma parte do código**... No caso eu estou colocando assim no array `{mes:mes, venda:vendaMes}` como faço pra ele pegar e verificar o item **mes** e se tiver adiciona o **venda** em um novo array e se não tiver insere o **0** ?

Comment: var defaultArrayMesVenda = [{mes: 1, venda: 0}, {mes:2, venda: 0}, {mes:3, venda: 0}, {mes:4, venda:0}, {mes:5, venda:0}, {mes:6, venda:0}, {mes:7, venda:0}, {mes:8, venda:0}, {mes:9, venda:0}, {mes:10, venda:0}, {mes:11, venda:0}, {mes:12, venda:0}];



_.unionBy(mesVendaArray, defaultArrayMesVenda, 'mes');

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira de fazer isso é preenchendo as lacunas de um segundo objeto:

```
var el = [{4:3094}, {6:9873}, {7:6531}, {12:10937}];
var complete = [{1:0},{2:0},{3:0},{4:0},{5:0},{6:0},{7:0},{8:0},{9:0},{10:0},{11:0},{12:0}];
complete.forEach(function(v, i) {
    if (el[i]) {    
       complete[Object.keys(el[i])] = el[i];
    } 
});

console.log(complete);
```